# How do I correctly check for a cookie in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, twig

I am trying to use twig annotation in my view to detect whether a certain cookie value has been set, but I'm not very familiar with twig and it's not currently working.

First, I have set the cookie in a controller, and I can see that it is present from my browser. Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['accept-cookie'])) {
    setcookie("acceptCookies", "true", time() + (86400 * 300));
}
```

In my browser I can view the cookie and confirm that the content is correctly set to true.

Now in my view I need to check that the cookie is present, if it is not then a cookie banner should be displayed. Here is the code:

```
{% if app.request.cookies.get("acceptCookies") != null %}
    <h1>Cookies are set!</h1>
{% else %}
    <div id="cookieBanner">
        <div id="cookieContainer">
            <p>We use cookies on this website. By using this website, we'll assume that you consent to <a href="/cookies">the cookies we set.</a></p>
            <a href="?accept-cookie" class="button">Okay, continue.</a>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

According to the documentation I've read this should work correctly, however, it continues to display the cookie banner even though I can see that the browser is present in my browser.

How should I approach solving this?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is the best way to access your cookies in a twig template!

This variable contains all your cookies

`{% app.request.cookies %}`

Example:

`{% if app.request.cookies.has('acceptCookies') %}
Yes you accept cookies
{% endif %}`

see full tutorial: http://enarion.net/news/2012/access-cookies-in-a-twig-template-using-symfony2/

Also take a look a the symfony docs on how to set cookies the correct way: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#setting-cookies

Comment: Thanks, I agree that looks like the correct way to do it. And that is one of the tutorials I checked when researching how to check for cookies in twig. Unfortunately using app.request.cookies.has like you suggest doesn't work either. I suspect I may be dealing with larger problems...

Comment: i edited my answer with an extra example on how to set cookies (see last link)

Comment: Thanks. It might be a stupid question, but will twig read the cookie differently if it has been set without regard for symfony's method? The site I am working on does not actually use symfony2, but it's own custom MVC that also employs twig annotation. I have tried contacting the original creator of the site, but he wasn't able to identify where I was going wrong unfortunately.

Comment: Just some clarification: the custom MVC, from what I can tell, is a modified variation of Symfony2. But I've never really dealt with Symfony either so I might be wrong.

Comment: Don't know if the usage of an symfony2 based mvc will change the behavior in twig, but can u use the symfony2 way of setting a cookie in your framework? If so, ttry it that way

Answer (score 0):

In your php, you check the `$_GET['accept_cookie']` value which do not exist in your html twig code. That's why the browser display the cookie banner. You must use form to take the `$_GET['accept_cookie']`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Why does $_GET need to appear in my twig code? The cookie is set in the controller and functions fine from what I can see. It's only reading the cookie once it is set that is the problem.